# Listing Elements of Array / List<String>

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, arraylist

I found some helpful post, but need clarification. I have a matrix with a list of numbers in it, separated by a space between each number.

```
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

I have read that data into my program with the following code:

```
string[] listData = File.ReadAllLines("\\Folder1\\GridDat.txt");
            List<string[]> partialData = new List<string[]>();

            // Read all lines and put them into this array
            foreach (string s in listData)
            {
                partialData.Add(s.Split(' '));
            }

            fileOut.WriteLine("{0}", partialData);
```

I believe I have read this into an array or a List of strings, but not sure how access the data from here, so I can print it out to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain how you want it formatted in your output file, but this will print them one number on each line:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\temp\\numbers.txt");

var lineArray = lines.SelectMany(x=>x.Split(' '));

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\\temp\\txt.txt", lineArray);
```

[SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx)

This will allow you to pull in the data, manipulate the numbers and then put it back in the original format:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\temp\\numbers.txt");

var lineArray = lines.Select(x =>
{
    var numbers = x.Split(' ');
    //do stuff with individual numbers here.
    return string.Join(" ", numbers);
}
);

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\\temp\\txt.txt", lineArray);
```

[Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I basically want it output as it is displayed in the text file. I may need to touch certain points of data such as row 4, column 17, for example.

Comment: That was it thank you! I wasn't using the .Select as I should have been doing.

Comment: This will pull in the data, and where I put the comment you can manipulate the individual numbers, then it will stitch it back together and print it back out the way it was originally.